# ReactJS: Prop referencing a state var. is not updated after parent's state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Top` component which has a checkbox and also a child `MyValidator` component. When the checkbox changes, I have a handler in the Top component which sets its State var, `this.state.activeItemLocked`. The `MyValidator` child component specified in `Top` has a Prop with this state var.

However, when the Top Component changes its state, the `MyValidator` is not refreshed with this new change, even though it should render the current value which is its own state var received from Props:

**Top**

```
class Top extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);   

    this.state = {
        activeItemLocked: false;
    }; 
}

render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.activeItemLocked} id="bChkboxLocked" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}></input>
         <label htmlFor="bChkboxLocked">Locked</label>
         <MyValidator value={this.state.activeItemLocked}></MyValidator>        
       <div>
    );
}

// Handler to set State var. in Top upon Checkbox Toggle
handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      activeItemLocked: e.target.checked ? true : false
    });     
};
```

}

**MyValidator**

```
class MyValidator extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        value: this.props.value // Initialize MyValidator's State var. from Props
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={{"color":"red"}}>Checkbox current state: {this.state.value}</div>
    );
}
```

}

**Issue** : Upon `Top`'s state change, the Prop-based `MyValidator` state change does not occur (it does not display the current value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a class component, there are many ways you can achieve this. 2 of them are:

1. [Don't copy a props to a state variable. Instead just use the props.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)

```
class MyValidator extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{"color":"red"}}>Checkbox current state: {this.props.value}. </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. Use `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
class MyValidator extends Component {

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.value !== state.value) {
      return {value: props.value}
    }
    return state;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{"color":"red"}}>Checkbox current state: {this.state.value}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor only runs once. So you need to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update child state before render:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props){
   return {
     value: props.value
   };
}
```

also convert the `boolean` value to a string so that it gets printed out:

`{this.state.lol.toString()}`

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-https-3eh52?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: THanks. Do I need something special to run codesandbox.io with React? Both FF and Chrome freeze, the panel says "Loading..." and the screen is blank.

Comment: Wow that is strange... are you in a special network that might be blocking downloading cdn scripts or something?

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm behind a work VPN. On my personal computer it works. Thanks again, much appreciated.